# How to override current language used inside an app

Tags: ios, localization

I've found testing localizations to be a slight pain since I have to go and change the device's language in order for the app to change.

How can I make my app "think" I changed my default language? I could then link that to a button or popover, but the actual changing of the language is the tricky part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the with any of the supported languages or regions by settings then in the option of the run target.

This fully described in [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html)

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to change the language while actually running the app. Is that a possibility or is this the closest I can come?

Comment: You can change the language while the app is running, but this will require al lot of code. You will need to write the language switch yourself, unless you need to it it is not worth the effort.

Comment: Gotcha. Didn't know about changing at run target, that will save some time, thanks!